# python arrays: averaging slope and intercept of datasets

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am having some difficulties achieving the following. Let's say I have two sets of data obtained from a test:

```
    import numpy as np
    a = np.array([[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0]]).T
    b = np.array([[0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5], [0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]]).T
```

where the data in the 0th column represents (in my case) displacement and the data in the 1th column represents the respective measured force values.

(Given data represents two lines with slopes of 2 and 1, both with a y-intercept of 0.)

Now I am trying to program a script that averages those two arrays despite the mismatched x-values, such that it will yield

```
    c = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5], [0.0, 0.75, 1.5,
         2.25, 3.0, 3.75, 4.5, 5.25]]).T
```

(A line with a slope of 1.5 and a y-intercept of 0.)

I tried my best using slicing and linear interpolation, however it seems like I cannot get my head around it (I am a beginner).

---

I'd be very glad for any input and tips and hope the information I gave to you is sufficient!

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear by what you mean when you say column, say nth element of a[0] and a[1] or something instead. You have two sets of data, a and b, but I have no clue from reading this what the two sets within a or within b are compared to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the coefficients (slope and intercept) of each dataset, obtain the mean, and fit that data to a new array of x values.

## Step by Step:

Fit deg-1 polynomial to each array `a`, and `b` using [`polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) to get the coefficients of each (slope and intercept):

```
coef_a = np.polyfit(a[:,0], a[:,1], deg=1)

coef_b = np.polyfit(b[:,0], b[:,1], deg=1)

>>> coef_a
array([  2.00000000e+00,   2.22044605e-16])
>>> coef_b
array([  1.00000000e+00,   1.33226763e-15])
```

Get the mean of those coefficients to use as the coefficients of `c`:

```
coef_c = np.mean(np.stack([coef_a,coef_b]), axis=0)

>>> coef_c
array([  1.50000000e+00,   7.77156117e-16])
```

Create new x-values for c using `np.arange`

```
c_x = np.arange(0,4,0.5)

>>> c_x
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5])
```

use [`polyval`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html) to fit your new `c` coeficients to your new `x` values:

```
c_y = np.polyval(coef_c, c_x)

>>> c_y
array([  7.77156117e-16,   7.50000000e-01,   1.50000000e+00,
         2.25000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,   3.75000000e+00,
         4.50000000e+00,   5.25000000e+00])
```

Put your `c_x` and `c_y` values together using `stack`:

```
c = np.stack([c_x, c_y])

>>> c
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e+00,
          1.50000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,   2.50000000e+00,
          3.00000000e+00,   3.50000000e+00],
       [  7.77156117e-16,   7.50000000e-01,   1.50000000e+00,
          2.25000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,   3.75000000e+00,
          4.50000000e+00,   5.25000000e+00]])
```

If you round that to 2 decimals, you'll see it's the same as your desired outcome:

```
>>> np.round(c, 2)
array([[ 0.  ,  0.5 ,  1.  ,  1.5 ,  2.  ,  2.5 ,  3.  ,  3.5 ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.75,  1.5 ,  2.25,  3.  ,  3.75,  4.5 ,  5.25]])
```

## In a single statement:

```
c = np.stack([np.arange(0, 4, 0.5),
              np.polyval(np.mean(np.stack([np.polyfit(a.T[0], a.T[1], 1),
                                           np.polyfit(b.T[0], b.T[1], 1)]),
                                 axis=0),
                         np.arange(0, 4, 0.5))])

>>> c
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   5.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e+00,
          1.50000000e+00,   2.00000000e+00,   2.50000000e+00,
          3.00000000e+00,   3.50000000e+00],
       [  7.77156117e-16,   7.50000000e-01,   1.50000000e+00,
          2.25000000e+00,   3.00000000e+00,   3.75000000e+00,
          4.50000000e+00,   5.25000000e+00]])
```

Comment: I think trying to cram everything into one statement is costing you clarity here.

Comment: You're right: Editted to include each step separately

Comment: Wow, thanks you! So much effort put into your answer, I'm glad that there's people like you out there!
Not only is your code working perfectly, but also do I think I just got a little better programmer by understanding it :))